# Time in Big O notation for if(N^2%N==0)

Tags: algorithm, time, big-o, complexity-theory

I wanted to understand how to calculate time complexity on if statements.
I got this problem:

```
sum = 0;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<i*i;j++)
    {
        if(j%i==0)
        {
            for(k=0;k<j;k++)
            {
                sum++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I understand that for lines (1) and (2) I have n^3 in total, and according to my professor the total time is n^4, I also see that the if statement is testing to check when the remainder of n^2/n is 0, and the for loop in line (4) in my opinion should be n^2, but I don't know how to calculate it in order for lines (3) through (4) have O(n) in total. Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how the total time can be `O(n^4)` -- it looks like `O(n^3)` to me.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that's because the second loop runs till 'i*i', that is 'n^2' times.

Comment: @user58697 But it increments by `i` each time (nothing happens when `j` is not a multiple of `i`).

Comment: well the first for loop has I going from 1 to N(total size) and then the next for loop has j going from 1 to I*I(N*N) so I know the first and second for loop have O(n^3) but I want to know what it has from the if statement down

Comment: My professor tried to explained but I didn't understand, said that the if would account for O(1) but the for loop inside he wrote it as having O(n) which makes no sense since it goes from 0 to j(which goes to I^2 or N^2)

Answer (score 3):

Let's compute `sum` by rewriting the program and observing some math facts:

Phase 1:

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < i*i; j += i) {
            sum += j;
        }
    }
```

Phase 2  (use arithmetic progression):

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += i*i * (i + 1) / 2;
    }
```

Phase 3:

```
    Sum of cubes is a polynomial 4th degree
```

So, `sum = O(n^4)`. The original program achieves that by adding 1, so it needs `O(n^4)` additions.

Answer (score 0):

There are 6 lines of actual code here.  (You had them all on one line which was very hard to read.  John Odom fixed that.)

1)  Runs in O(1)

2)  Runs in O(n), total is O(n)

3)  Runs in O(n^2), total is O(n^3)

4)  Runs in O(1), this filters the incoming from O(n^3) to O(n^2)

Edit:  I missed the fact that this loop went to n^2 instead of n.

5)  Runs in O(n) but this n is the square of the original n, thus it's really O(n^2), total is O(n^4)

6)  Runs O(1), total is O(n^4)

Thus the total time is O(n^4)

Note, however:

```
for(j=1;j<i*i;j++)
    {
        if(j%i==0)
```

This would be much better rewritten as

```
for(j=i;j<i*i;j+=i)
```

(hopefully I got the syntax right, it's been ages since I've done C.)

Comment: shouldn't 5) be O(n^2) since k is going to j which is going to I^2 where each I is going to n therefore making k go from 0 to n^2?

Comment: @JorgeVargasMoreno Argh, you're right--I was focused on the filter and missed the fact the second loop goes to n^2.

Comment: ok, now how does that filter work, why does it make the total go from O(n^3) to O(n^2)? does that happen for every if or is it because of the % being checked in the if?

Comment: @JorgeVargasMoreno Only 1 in n times around the loop is the conditional true.  Look at how I rewrote the line, you can see it executes i times.